# How to draw or render a Sphere in WinRT?

Tags: c#, 3d, winrt-xaml

I am having some trouble figuring out how to draw a 3d shape (a Sphere in this case) in WinRT.  I looked at Matrix3DProjection and Matrix3D but appears to be more of a perspective transform for 2D objects to make them appear 3D.

I also looked at some libraries like SharpDX which appears to be able to do a number of things but I can't seem to find just a simple example of how to just render a shape like a sphere.

My end goal is to render a smaller sphere orbiting a larger one, but baby steps first, I have to be able to actually create the shape in the first place.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharpDX, you can take a look at the Geometrics Toolkit sample, it is implemented only for Desktop, but exactly the same code will run on WinRT. It is quite simple to draw geometric primitives with it - the code that does loading and drawing is [here](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/blob/master_integration/Samples/Toolkit/Common/Geometrics/GeometricsGame.cs).